# matplotlib runtime error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed matplotlib on windows with python 2.7. I am trying to do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
plot.plot([1,2,3][1,2,3])
```

This causes the following errors:

[image]

[image]

Appreciate any help you can offer ..

Regards

Comment: Since I'm running Ubuntu myself I can't try the pythonw, but my first guess is that it has something to do with that. Try just use the python interpreter and import pyplot there and try to plot. If that doesn't work either then you at least know if it's the import command that is causing the error or the plot function call.

Comment: There is no error when I run the code in the interpreter

Comment: See where is says "View Problem details"? It would be _really_ useful to know that information here!

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you're missing a komma:

```
plot.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
```

The termination behaviour for me is not reproducable. If I work with spyder and python 2.7 it simply gives me an syntax error. So tell a little bit more about the error. Does it still exist with the inserted komma?

Comment: Hey Jonathan - Sorry about the comma, this was a mistake in writing the example - the error remains with the comma

Comment: Does the import command itself work? If yes: Are you able to invoke the plot function as:

    plot.plot() ?

? Or will this also crash?

Comment: The import works fine, and I am able to run the code without any issues (obviously the plot doesn't appear) - it is only until I go to run the module again, I see the errors above